# Infinitely many prime numbers of the form $n^{2^k}+1$?

Tags: nt.number-theory, prime-numbers

I am not a specialist of number theory, so please excuse my ignorance: is the following question still an open problem?
Let $k \in \mathbb{N}^*$, are there infinitely many prime numbers of the form $n^{2^k}+1$?

Comment: What's known about the problem if both n and k are allowed to vary?

Comment: @Qiaochu: In this problem, allowing n and k to vary among positive integers is the same as setting k=1 and letting n vary.

Answer (score 10):

Your question is still open. It is a special case of [Schinzel's Hypothesis H](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schinzel%27s_hypothesis_H) applied to the polynomial $f(x)=x^{2^k}+1$.

As Bjorn mentions in his comment, the case of $k=1$ is a particularly famous unsolved problem. It is the fourth of [Landau's problems](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Landau%27s_problems) (Edmund Landau was a famous German number theorist during the early twentieth century).

Comment: This may not be clear from the Wikipedia article: Bunyakovsky's conjecture is not known for _any_ particular polynomial of degree greater than 1.  

Answer (score 4):

It took me a while to find this: http://www.pnas.org/content/94/4/1054.full

Anyway by Friedlander and Iwaniec (1997). They proved that there are infinitely many primes of the form $x^2 + y^4 .$ They mention near the end that they do not have a proof for primes of the form $x^2 + y^6 $ but would like one. So there is a way to go to settle $x^2 + 1.$

FYI, what I did (not remembering title, authors, anything but the result) was write a program to give the primes $x^2 + y^4 $ and put the first dozen in Sloane's sequence site search feature.

Comment: I think that the best result thus far is Iwaniec's proof that there are infinitely many positive integers n such that n^2+1 is divisible by at most 2 primes.

Comment: http://oeis.org/classic/A028916

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it is still an open question

Comment: [citation needed]?

Comment: The conjectured answer is yes: see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bunyakovsky_conjecture or the vast generalization in http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bateman-Horn_conjecture .  But it is certainly unknown since a positive answer for any k would give a positive answer for k=1, which is a famous unsolved problem.

Comment: @Alison: it seems to me to be a non-trivial problem to give a citation which proves that a given question is still open!

Comment: The conjecture that there are infinitely many primes of the form n^2+1 is the first entry (A1) in Richard Guy's Unsolved Problems in Number Theory. 

Comment: There's a version of Guy's book in our maths library that says it's a conjecture that x^n+y^n=z^n has no non-trivial solutions when n>=3 ;-)